# angular unit testing a method having a cont and a for loop

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I am doing unit test in Angular using jasmine. I have a method containing a `const` and a `for` loop. Below is the code:

```
private initializeFilterArrays() {
    const today = new Date().getFullYear();
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      this.yearsFilter.push(today - i);
    }
  }
```

The html for this:

```
<button (click)="initializeFilterArrays()" id="init">Filter</button>
```

The spec.ts:

```
it('clicking on "Filter" should filter', () => {
   const filterBtn = debugElement.query(By.css('#init'));
   filterBtn.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
   ...
}
```

So, in the testcase, what do I write after I triggered the click so that all the lines of the method are executed? I want to test whether all the lines are executed or not. And how to make all lines execute? What to do if I want total code coverage?

Comment: What lines are executed? Of `initializeFilterArrays` or where it displays?

Comment: I want all the lines of `initializeFilterArrays` to be executed. Because I want total code-coverage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assert that the `yearsFilter` instance variable has the proper length.

```
it('clicking on "Filter" should filter', () => {
   const filterBtn = debugElement.query(By.css('#init'));
   filterBtn.triggerEventHandler('click', {});
   expect(component.yearsFilter.length).toBe(/* new length you expect with all the pushes */);
   // you can also do other assertions on the yearsFilter array as well.
   // Edit 
   expect(component.yearsFilter.includes(2021)).toBeTruthy();
}
```

Comment: but can I test whether the const today contains 2021?

Comment: You can't do an assertion on `today` since it is not a public method or instance variable however you can check the `yearsFilter` array to have a 2021 entry. Check out my edit.